# Count How many Times Value Appears but based on a limit

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a question of how to count the amount of repeats, but setting a limit to the counts.

Want to find how many values repeat over 2 times for example

So take names, stored in a column (Jeremy, Jake, Jake, Jake) in a table named names

So I want an output of just:

```
Name | Number_Repeats
Jake | 3
```

I assume the query would be

I am getting errors trying this, Help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT names.name,
       count(*) AS Number_Repeats
FROM NAMES
WHERE count(*) > 2
GROUP BY names.name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `having clause` instead of `where clause` as you are applying a filter over aggregation

```
 SELECT names.name, count(*) as Number_Repeats 
 FROM names  GROUP BY names.name
 having count(*) > 2
```